# One mole of solute (NaCl) is dissolved in 1 litre water. The molarity of solution is

Tags: concentration

> One mole of solute ($\ce{NaCl}$) is dissolved in $\pu{1 L}$ of water. The molarity of the solution is:
>
> A) $\pu{<1M}$
>
> B) $\pu{>1M}$
>
> C) $\pu{=1M}$
>
> D) $\pu{=2M}$

**My answer:** It’s a fairly simple question so, I did what anybody would do.

$\mathrm{Molarity}=\frac{\text{No. of moles}}{\text{volume of solution}}$

$\mathrm{Molarity}=1$

That is the obvious answer, and it’s probably right, but the answer given is $\pu{<1M}$. I just wanted to confirm that the answer given is right or wrong. If it is right, why?

Comment: Look up the difference between molar and molal solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer $<\pu{1M}$ is correct.

Suppose you have $\pu{1L}$ ($\pu{1dm^3}$) of water and then you add your salt. When you add your salt the volume of the solution increases so now you have $\pu{1 mol}$ of $\ce{NaCl}$ in more than $\pu{1L}$ of solution. That means that you can't have a $\pu{1M}$ solution anymore.

If you want a $\pu{1M}$ solution then:

1. Add $\pu{1 mol}$ of salt in a flask.
2. Add water until you reach $\pu{1L}$ of volume.

EDIT: when you add salt, the volume of the solution increases slightly and less than what you expect(volume of water + volume of dry salt).